# Rotate circle around triangle canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to spin a circle around a triangle using canvas. Have this code from earlier, but here is the circle in the middle, and a rectangle spinning, i want the circle to spin and have a triangle in the middle. Can someone help?

Here is the JS code i have:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx = 100;
var cy = 100;
var rectWidth = 15;
var rectHeight = 10;
var rotation = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(cx, cy);
  ctx.rotate(rotation);
  ctx.strokeRect(-rectWidth / 2 + 20, -rectHeight / 2, rectWidth, rectHeight);
  ctx.restore();

  rotation += Math.PI / 180;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your code to draw the requested shapes and added comments to describe, what i am doing in the snippet below.

```js
var canvas = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("canvas"));
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx = 100;
var cy = 100;
var rotation = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function animate() {
    //Clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //Draw center figure
    /*
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    */
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(cx - 10, cy - 10);
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy + 10);
    ctx.lineTo(cx + 10, cy - 10);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    //Rotate canvas
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx, cy);
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
    //Draw rotating object
    /*ctx.strokeRect(-rectWidth / 2 + 20, -rectHeight / 2, rectWidth, rectHeight);*/
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(20, 0, 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    //Rotate canvas back
    ctx.restore();
    //Save rotation
    rotation += Math.PI / 180;
    //Request next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

It sounds like you lack experience with `HTML Canvas` manipulation, so i would like to recommend some [MDN's official canvas tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial).

If you have further questions feel free to open new questions with more code-specific problems in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to moving objects without using the `ctx.translate` or the `ctx.rotate`

We can use `Math.sin` and `Math.cos` to move around in a circular or elliptical motion.
Once you understand this approach you open the door for many possibilities, for example you can make the spins relative to other objects.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var rotation = 0;
setInterval(animate, 10);

function animate(rx, ry, speed) { 
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  draw(120, 80, 1)
  draw(240, 80, 10/3)
}

function draw(rx, ry, speed) {    
  var x = Math.cos(rotation) * 50 + rx
  var y = Math.sin(rotation) * 50 + ry
  
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    x += Math.sin(rotation * i/speed) * 20
    y += Math.cos(rotation * i/speed) * 20/i
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(x, y, 8/i, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  rotation += Math.PI / 180;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=170 width=400></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes good point that for moving an object in a circular way trigo might be just what is needed. But some basic explanations would probably improve greatly this answer (so readers can actually "*understand this approach*"). Also, beware of what you are saying. Your setting of x and y values of the arc method are just equivalent to a `translate(x, y); arc(0,0..`. So all you can do with these two params can actually [be done](https://jsfiddle.net/bnh7j1pk/) with a simple translate. One thing that would be harder to do with only trig...

Comment: ... though would be to change the scale and skew of your shapes, [like rotate() does](https://jsfiddle.net/bnh7j1pk/1/). Also once you get matrix transforms, it's not that hard to make [objects relatives to each others](https://jsfiddle.net/bnh7j1pk/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<code>    
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx=100;
var cy=100;
var rectWidth=15;
var rectHeight=10;
var rotation=0;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();

    var radius = 8;        
    ctx.moveTo(cx - radius, cy + radius);        
    ctx.lineTo(cx, cy - radius);        
    ctx.lineTo(cx + radius , cy + radius);        
    ctx.lineTo(cx - radius, cy + radius);        
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
    ctx.strokeRect(-rectWidth/2+20,-rectHeight/2,rectWidth,rectHeight);
    ctx.restore(); 
    rotation+=Math.PI/180;
}
</code>
```