# Rotate triangle around circle (2D)

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, html5-canvas

I'm trying to rotate a triangle around a circle, the triangle should always face outwards, meaning it should rotate around the circle, AND around its center I'm guessing.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536404/rotate-circle-around-triangle-canvas) question, which is something like what I need, but just in reverse.
Another thing I need is to have the triangle pointed at the user's mouse coords. aka the triangle is something like an arrow.

Comment: Your situation needs the same "save, translate, rotate, draw, restore" process as given in the answer to the question you linked. If you've done that and are having trouble still, please show your attempt.

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far, as I'm not sure about the math required to rotate the triangle like that... I'm not really having issues with the code part, but more like with the *math* part

Comment: You don't need to rotate the triangle. Just rotate the canvas and it will draw the triangle rotated for you.

Comment: Yeah... thats the issue... I'm having issues with the *rotation math*

Comment: Mate just... *try it*. Rotate the canvas by something like 30 degrees and draw a triangle. Ta-da, it's rotated by 30 degrees. No rotation math needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just edited the code you linked and replaced the rectangle with a triangle, and `animate()` with a mouse move listener, of course:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx = 100;
var cy = 100;
var radious = 10;
var gap = 5;
var triangleHeight = 25;
var triangleBase = 10;
redraw(cx + 1, cy);

function redraw(mx, my)
{
  mox = mx-cx;
  moy = my-cy;
  rotation = Math.atan2(moy, mox);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx, cy, radious, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(cx, cy);
  ctx.rotate(rotation);
  ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(radious+gap, -triangleBase/2);
    ctx.lineTo(radious+gap, triangleBase/2);
    ctx.lineTo(radious+gap+triangleHeight, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(radious+gap, -triangleBase/2)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.restore();

}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
redraw(e.pageX, e.pageY);
}, false);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

BTW, it's my very first piece of code in JS, so, feel free to correct my code if something is funny.

Comment: Quite an easy to understand solution! Thank you! I didn't know of the existence of the atan2 function... And i guess i was overthinking things a bit. This would work perfectly, thanks!